# Java 8: extract a substream from a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of Objects, from which I need to extract a Stream which has only some of the object attributes.

For example, from a `Stream<Car>`, I need to extract a `Stream<CarDetails>`.

```
Car {
   String name;
   String model;
   Engine e;
   CarType t;
   ...
}
```

I want to extract a `Stream` of objects having type `CarDetails`:

```
CarDetails {
   String name;
   String model;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with `map`, assuming you have the required `CarDetails` constructor :

```
Stream<Car> cars = ...
Stream<CarDetails> details = cars.map(c -> new CarDetails(c.getName(),c.getModel()));
```

Comment: Alternately, using a CarDetailsFactory:

`cars.map(CarDetailsFactory::createCarDetails)` 

or a method that `Car` provides:

`cars.map(Car::createDetailsObject)`

Comment: Thanks.. just to extend my question little bit more.. what if `Car.model` is a `Set<Model>` and I still want the `stream<CarDetails>` with individual model and car name..

Comment: @Sneha In that case you can use `flatMap` - `cars.flatMap(c->c.getModels().stream().map(m->new CarDetails(c.getName(),m)))`.

Comment: Just to be clear "details" is not a "substream". 

Since cars has been operated upon, you no longer can use the cars stream. If you need another stream from cars, you need to to create a new cars stream.